# Django Get multiple fields from database

Tags: python, django

Is there anyway that I could retrieve multiple fields from Django database?

In `Model` class I have:

```
class Advert(models.Model):
    cat        = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    advertiser = models.ForeignKey(Advertiser)
    country    = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    city       = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    title      = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body       = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    link       = models.URLField()

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```

The function `__unicode__(self)` would return only the title of the Advertise.

How can I get the fields: `(title, body, link)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use Django's [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) function. From the example:

```
>>> Advert.objects.values_list('title', 'body', 'link')
[(u'Title', u'This is a body text line.', u'http://example.com/'), 
(u'Title 2', u'This is another body text line.', u'http://example.com/foobar')]
```

Any desired filters and annotations should be put before the `values_list` call. If you only want one field for each record, and want it in a flat list, add `flat=True`:

```
>>> Advert.objects.values_list('link', flat=True)
[u'http://example.com/', u'http://example.com/foobar']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'{} - {} - {}'.format(self.title, self.body, self.link)
```

Yes, as marked below, use `u` to mark it as unicode string

Comment: `__unicode__` returning `str` is not good. Better return unicode string e.g. `return u'{} - {} - {}'.format(self.title, self.body, self.link)`

Comment: From the question: "The function `__unicode__(self)` would return only the title of the Advertise." Redefining `__unicode__` is not desired.

Comment: His question is interpretable. Nevertheless, he has good answers below and he started coding without reading minimal documentation :P

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the fact that the ORM is exactly that, an *object*-relational mapper. When you do `my_advert = Advert.objects.get(whatever)` you get an instance of Advert, which contains all the fields. So you can do `my_advert.title`, `my_advert.body`, etc.

Comment: And `filter` or `all` could be used instead of `get` to get a list of objects, and `values_list` (or `values`) could return just the fields of interest so the database doesn't have to return all the objects' fields and construct objects out of them. Unfortunately, the OP doesn't specify how they got the `Advert`(s) in question...